# How do I "UTF-8 encode" my JavaScript files so that Google Chrome can use them in an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, utf-8

I am writing a fairly simple extension for Chrome. The main graphical body of it (the part dealing with html, i.e. the front-end) works fine, but when I try to include a second JavaScript file that uses Jquery's $.ajax() function to return some info from another page to the front-end, Chrome throws the following error and won't let me load the extension:

> Could not load extension from "Path\to\extension". Could not load file "filename.js" for content script. It isn't UTF-8 encoded.

I don't honestly know enough about UTF-8 encoding to be able to tell what would make Chrome say that about my file. I have no special characters, no accent marks or anything, which i know can screw things up. I haven't been able to find a good solution anywhere, either.

Comment: You are probably saving the file as UNICODE. What editor are you using?

Comment: Notepad++, which, after Ekkehard's comment, I realized defaults to ANSI. I copied a bit of text from Wikipedia into a comment, and it apparently used a weird form of hyphen that was UTF-8 nonstandard.

Comment: Notepad++, at least the version I use -- v.5.6.4, also has a menu item for Encoding that will automatically convert it from ANSI/Unicode/etc. to UTF-8.  I have used this feature to make my own Chrome Extensions.

Comment: Downloaded Notepad++ and used the menu for encoding it from ANSI to UTF-8 - that cured it! thanks @NathanR for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to UTF-8 encode your files, is to use an editor that allows you to choose that encoding. If you can't do that, there are (fairly standard) tools on linux/unix system to check (file) and to change (iconv, recode) the encoding. If you use Windows, such tools can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue even though the file was saved a UTF-8. However the code contained a `U+FFFF` character, which is [invalid by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)). It's the same for `U+FFFE`.

The solution was to use `"\uffff"` instead of using the character directly.